# Segmentation Fault while using MPI and OpenCV together

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, mpi

I am trying to learn MPI in C++. I have some knowledge of OpenCV so I tried writing a program using both MPI and OpenCV. This may sound stupid but for the purpose of learning I tried capturing an image from webcam on thread 0 and passed the image to thread 1 for converting to grayscale and displaying the grayscale image.

This is how I compile the code:
`` mpic++ opencv.cpp `pkg-config opencv --libs` ``

The code compiles sucessfully but when I run the executable, an image shows up on the screen for a fraction of a second and this is what I see on the terminal

```
~/mpi$ mpirun -np 2 ./a.out
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl S_FMT
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l1: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl VIDIOCSPICT

[arch:09670] *** Process received signal *** 
[arch:09670] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[arch:09670] Signal code: Address not mapped (1) 
[arch:09670] Failing at address: 0x218ac50
[arch:09670] [ 0] /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x10740)[0x7f422fcac740]
[arch:09670] [ 1] /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4(_ZNK2cv11_InputArray6getMatEi+0x203)[0x7f4233c8c113]
[arch:09670] [ 2] /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4(_ZN2cv8cvtColorERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEii+0x50)[0x7f4232c25de0]
[arch:09670] [ 3] ./a.out[0x408f54]
[arch:09670] [ 4] /usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f422e9e9800]
[arch:09670] [ 5] ./a.out[0x408c19]
[arch:09670] *** End of error message *** 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 9670 on node arch exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here's the code

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cv::Mat_<uint> img(640,480);
    cv::Mat_<uint> gray(640,480);
    cv::VideoCapture cam(0);

    int rank, nproc, j=0;

    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // MPI datatype for 8UC3 image
    MPI_Datatype mat_8uc3;
    MPI_Type_contiguous(sizeof(img), MPI_BYTE, &mat_8uc3);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mat_8uc3);

    // MPI datatype for 8UC1 image
    MPI_Datatype mat_8uc1;
    MPI_Type_contiguous(sizeof(gray), MPI_BYTE, &mat_8uc1);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mat_8uc1);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc); // number of processes
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);  // rank of the current process

    /*
     * Thread 0 captures the image from camera
     * and sends the image to process 1 for processing
     * thread 1 converts the image to grayscale and
     * displays the image
     */

    if (rank == 0) {
        // capture the image and send to thread 1
        while (1) { 
            cam >> img;
            cv::imshow("proc 0", img);
            MPI_Send(&img, 1, mat_8uc3, 1, j, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            cv::waitKey(40);
            j++;
        }
    }
    else if (rank == 1) {
        // receive the image, convert to grayscale and display
        while (1) {
            MPI_Recv(&img, 1, mat_8uc3, 0, j, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            cv::cvtColor(img, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            cv::imshow("proc 1", gray);
            cv::waitKey(20);
            j++;
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone point out where am I going wrong

Thanks

**EDIT:** (after user0815's answer)

On making the suggested changes the problem `Device or resource busy` is resolved but the program still gives a segfault.

```
[arch:01080] *** Process received signal *** 
[arch:01080] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[arch:01080] Signal code: Address not mapped (1) 
[arch:01080] Failing at address: 0x16bbf80
[arch:01080] [ 0] /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x10740)[0x7fea97322740]
[arch:01080] [ 1] /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4(_ZNK2cv11_InputArray6getMatEi+0x203)[0x7fea9b302113]
[arch:01080] [ 2] /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4(_ZN2cv8cvtColorERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEii+0x50)[0x7fea9a29bde0]
[arch:01080] [ 3] ./a.out[0x408fc3]
[arch:01080] [ 4] /usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fea9605f800]
[arch:01080] [ 5] ./a.out[0x408c79]
[arch:01080] *** End of error message *** 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 1080 on node arch exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It looks like some other process has a lock on the camera. I think there should be a way to verify you have control of the camera before the `cam >> img` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently each process tries to open the camera. That is very likely to cause problems. Try to move the opening into the root specific section like so:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  cv::Mat_<uint> img(640,480);
  cv::Mat_<uint> gray(640,480);
  cv::VideoCapture cam;

  /* ... */
  if (rank == 0) {
    cam.open(0);
    /* ... */
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

**Update:**

I think the problem with your code is, that you can't simply transfer objects with `MPI_Send`. Also is the `sizeof` operator not valid on objects in general. If you want to transfer an object, you need to transfer the underlying data.

You could achieve this in your case by sending `img.data` with a size of `img.rows * img.cols * sizeof(uint)`. Then you can also use MPI_BYTE as data type and no custom types are required.

Some details about the internal structure of `cv::Mat_` can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat).

Answer (score 0):

As noticed by @user0851 , in your code, all processes try to open the camera and the opening of the camera can be perform by the root process alone.

The `Mat` object of openCV is quite complex and defining the corresponding `MPI_Datatype` may be complex too. Instead, sending the array of pixels `img.data` is much easier. Here is a little piece of code demonstrating how it could be done. It is compiled by `mpiCC main.cpp -o main -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core` and run by `mpirun -np 2 main`

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Mat img;
    Mat gray;


    int rank, nproc, j=0;

    size_t total;
    size_t elemsize;
    int sizes[3];

    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc); // number of processes
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);  // rank of the current process

    /*
     * Thread 0 captures the image from camera
     * and sends the image to process 1 for processing
     * thread 1 converts the image to grayscale and
     * displays the image
     */

    if (rank == 0) {
        VideoCapture cam(0);
        if(!cam.isOpened()){
            fprintf(stderr,"unable to open camera.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        // capture the image and send to thread 1
        while (1) { 
            cam >> img;
            cv::imshow("proc 0", img);

            if(j==0){
                sizes[2]=img.elemSize();
                Size s = img.size();
                sizes[0] = s.height;
                sizes[1] = s.width;
                MPI_Send( sizes, 3, MPI_INT, 1,0,   MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
            MPI_Send( img.data, sizes[0]*sizes[1]*3, MPI_CHAR,1,1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            cv::waitKey(40);
            j++;
        }
    }
    else if (rank == 1) {
        // receive the image, convert to grayscale and display
        while (1) {
            if(j==0){
                MPI_Recv( sizes,3, MPI_INT,0,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                img.create(sizes[0],sizes[1],CV_8UC3);
            }
            MPI_Recv( img.data, sizes[0]*sizes[1]*3, MPI_CHAR,0,1, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            cv::cvtColor(img, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            cv::imshow("proc 1", gray);
            cv::waitKey(20);
            j++;
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mat object is only a header structure that points to the memory that stores the image.
So you have some problems:
First, you create a `Mat` object sized 640X640 and than you read from the camera into that object. But `Mat` is just a header it is not a pointer to the data, The Mat object can be now of any width and height.

Second, `sizeof(Mat)` does not return the amount of memory allocated to the image, only the amount of memory the Mat object itself. The amount of memory needed for the image is `Mat.total()*Mat.elemSize()`